# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): setX is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and there's things that I'm still trying to comprehend such as the problem that I'm facing on an image management app which is connected to cloudinary (to upload images):

I have the following codes:

**App.js (parent)**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Gallery from './Gallery';
import TopBar from './TopBar';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';


function App() {

  return (

    <div className="all">

      <TopBar/>

        <div className="gallery-enclosure">
          <Gallery/>
        </div>


    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

**TopBar.js** (the component that contains the upload button and therefore the function that handles uploads

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Gallery from './Gallery'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

function TopBar() {


    const {image, setImage} = useState('')
    const {loading, setLoading} = useState(false)

    const uploadImage = async e => {
      const files = e.target.files
      const data = new FormData()
      data.append('file', files[0])
      data.append('upload_preset', 'projeto_react')
      setLoading(true)
      const res = await fetch(
        'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/antoniolima/image/upload',
        {
          method: 'POST',
          body: data
        }
      )
      const file = await res.json()

      setImage(file.secure_url)
      setLoading(false)
    }

    return (

        <div className="TopBar">     
        <div>
          <h2 id="title">
            Image Management
          </h2>
        </div>

        <div></div>

        <div className="App">
          <h1></h1>
          <input type="file"
                  name="file"
                  accept="image/*"
                  id="contained-button-file"
                  multiple
                  style={{display: "none"}}
                  placeholder="Upload an image"
                  onChange={uploadImage}
          />
          <label htmlFor="contained-button-file">
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" component="span">
                    Upload Image
                </Button>
          </label>
          {loading ? (
            <h3>Loading...</h3>

          ) : (
            <img src={image} style={{width: '300px'}} />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>



    );
  }

  export default TopBar;
```

The problem that I'm having a hard time understanding is, when I'm trying to upload a file it gives me the following error:
'*Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): setLoading is not a function*'

But this same function worked before I divided the code into different components in order to have a more organized work (and in order to create a state and props in my App class as I can't define them when I'm using a functional component).

I've been reading about arrow functions and inserting the const inside of a props parameter of an arrow function but I couldn't understand how I could define it and most of all access the equivalent of **setLoading()** in my **TopBar.js**,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're destructuring with object. Instead you should use array destructuring:

```
const [image, setImage] = useState('')
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
```

`useState` returns array in which first index has state value and second index has function to set state.

Comment: oh god, it was just that xD Thank you very much!

Comment: You just made my day. Thank you so much !